MAUI Searchbar icon not firing event
When i click search icon near text entry it doesnt trigger event, but when i do click enter on keyoboard it does work.
<SearchBar
    x:Name="SearchBar"
    Grid.Column="1"
    CancelButtonColor="White"
    FontSize="18"
    SearchButtonPressed="SearchBar_SearchButtonPressed"
    SearchCommand="{Binding SearchCommand}"
    SearchCommandParameter="{Binding Text, Source={x:Reference SearchBar}}"
    Text="{Binding SearchText}"
    VerticalOptions="Center" />

       public async void SearchBar_SearchButtonPressed(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           await DisplayAlert("hi", SearchBar.Text, "ok");
       }

Command is getting triggered as well on enter key
public ICommand SearchCommand => new Command<string>(async (text) =>
{
    await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("hi", $"{text} - {this.SearchText}", "ok");
});

whats wrong with it?

use either the command or the event handler, not both

yes i know but i need event to be triggered on icon click, not on keyboard enter press

as i read searchbar supports that event, but in my case that doesnt work

What do you mean by "it doesn't trigger event"? Does the event handler not get called or does the alert not show up? Have you placed a breakpoint in the event handler?

using SearchBar there must be 2 ways to trigger my 'SearchBar_SearchButtonPressed', one by taping on icon and second by pressing enter on keyoboard. everything is working with second approach, but not with first, it simply not calling binded SearchButtonPressed function. i used debugger as well.

What platform are you using?

Android, HONOR x8

There is no default event when clicking the Searchbar icon in Maui Android. But you may set an extra one through Handler. Here is an example,
In MainPage, I implement a ModifySearchbarOnlyforAndroid method in which   I use Handler.  I use FindViewById to find the search bar icon first and then set a Click event on it,
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //this.BindingContext = new MainPageViewModel();

            ModifySearchbarOnlyforAndroid();

        }


        void ModifySearchbarOnlyforAndroid()
        {
            Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.SearchBarHandler.Mapper.AppendToMapping("MyCustomization", (handler, view) =>
            {
#if ANDROID
                var searchicon = handler.PlatformView.FindViewById(Resource.Id.search_mag_icon);
                searchicon.SetOnClickListener(new CustomClickListener());
#endif
            });
        }

This is CustomClickListener,
#if ANDROID
    public class CustomClickListener : Java.Lang.Object, IOnClickListener
    {
 
        public void OnClick(Android.Views.View? v)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine("123");
            // add your code here,
        }

    }
#endif

So, the difference is, instead of adding your logic in SearchBar_SearchButtonPressed event handler, now you may add your code in OnClick method in your CustomClickListener.
